# Unwanted blank page prepended to large table

Tags: tables, blank-page

Problem-ku:

```
A page-long table
Gets a blank page prepended
I do not want this
```

The table is very large (69x20) but fits on one page.

Here's the code I'm using at the beginning and end of the mega-table.

**Before**:

```
\newgeometry{left=1cm,top=1.5cm}
\bibpunct{}{}{;}{n}{}{,}
\begin{table}[H]
  \footnotesize
  \begin{center}
    \tabcolsep=0.11cm
    \begin{tabular}{ |r||l|l|l||l|l|l|l||l|l|l|l||l|l||l|l|l||l|l|l|}
      \hline
```

**After**:

```
     \hline
    \end{tabular}\\    
    \caption{The caption\\$^{1}$\footnotesize{A footnote}}
    \label{tab:BigFrameworkChart}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,}
\restoregeometry
```

How the heck do I get rid of this extra page?

Comment: As always, please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: using `[H]` makes it almost inevitable that you get large white spaces in the document. Just don't use `[H]` and LaTeX will float the table to avoid such gaps.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this tabularx? (The sample fragment uses tabular not tabularx)

Comment: Why are `\bibpunct` instructions in this code? And why do you need `\footnotesize` for the `\footnote` instruction if that's already the font size in effect for the page?

Comment: jon: I would but the table includes unpublished academic work

@DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the (working) suggestion! And yes, I didn't mean tabularx.

Mico: the bibpunct's in there because It has to be there in the table, and I didn't want to leave anything from the table setup out. The footnotesize bit is just some redundancy left over from changing the table around many times. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @williamstome a minimal example shouldn't have the real data, you can replace each entry by `x` the less text that is there the easier it is to debug, it just needs to be a complete document taht shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off using the `afterpage` package and its command `\afterpage`, along the lines of the following code snippet. By the way, you may want to consider (i) getting rid of all interior single vertical lines in the table and (ii) replacing all double vertical lines with single vertical lines.

```
\afterpage{%   % be sure to load the "afterpage" package in the document's preamble
\newgeometry{left=1cm,top=1.5cm}
\begin{table}[p!] % don't use [H]
  \footnotesize
  \centering % don't use "center" environment
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.11cm}
    \begin{tabular}{ |r|| *{3}{l|}| *{4}{l|}| *{4}{l|} |l|l|| *{3}{l|}| *{3}{l|}}
      \hline
      % [body of table]
      \hline
    \end{tabular}   
    \caption{The caption}
    \label{tab:BigFrameworkChart}
\end{table}
\clearpage % flush the float
\restoregeometry} % end of \afterpage group
```